# Is it safe to use a stereo cable to carry dual mono audio?

Tags: stereo, cable, mono

My mixer takes stereo line input via 2 mono TS jacks.
My e-drum outputs stereo via 2 mono TS jacks as well.

Normally I will need to run 2 mono cables with TS jacks at each end from e-drum to mixer.

But I'm thinking about using a stereo cable and split them into 2 TS jacks at each end, using common ground. One less cable to maintain.

Is it safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stereo cables aren't special in any sense that would stop them from operating as independent halves. A common ground might cause some issues if you have two sources with different earth grounds, but in general this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Agreed - but splitting 2-core & [single] earth is not a fun task [I play a Rickenbacker, I've done it; needs heat-shrink on the bits that stick out & rubberised hot glue on the junctions] It would be easier to just buy paired cable.

Comment: Guess I'll just tie 2 mono cables with tape.